# query with single quote shown as empty

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysql-workbench

I have a form, that when you select a drop down of articles, the textbox is filled in with what you selected. Now it's working perfectly fine, except for when there's a 'single quote' in the article name.

I have a function for escaping the quotes by placing backslashes in front of them, which it does...

Now the Query produced is as follows:_

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE title='MySQL \'Inject' AND series='iOS Game Dev.' AND language='iOS' LIMIT 1
```

And I have a function which makes an object of the article and sets values of everything according to the row selected. When I display the array made by the function which runs the query it gives this..

```
Blog Object
(
 [id] => 
 [title] => 
 [publish_date] => 
 [author] => 
 [language] => 
 [series] => 
 [likes] => 
 [content] => 
 [position] => 
 [status] => 
 [last_updated] => 
)
```

It works if there isn't a single quote in the article name, but it doesn't fill the textbox because the array is empty.

More over the value stored in the database for the title is MySQL \'Inject . So I really don't get why it's doning this, I even tried run the query in MySQL Workbench and it returned nothing. So it's not a problem in my code I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Instead of using `=`, give `LIKE` a shot: `WHERE title LIKE '%MySQL \'Inject%'`

Comment: @juergend that would make the spostrophe go away completely, What if I want a single quote in the title?

Comment: @JahanzebKhan: No, it is still there. See this [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/337)

Comment: hmmm.... could you tell me one thing? Should I insert into the database like that then, meaning instead of inserting a \ before a quote in the database, use str replace to replace ' with '' and not use mysql_real_escape_string? and when i select it just select it normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you save yourself all the pain of worrying about escaping and just use prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters.

[This blog article](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/)  has a good tutorial.

Comment: If you mean making functions to develop the queries then that is what I did, that's how the query is formed....

Comment: No, that's not what I mean.  Did you look at the tutorial?  The essence of it is that, instead of placing the title/series/language into your SQL statement, you put placeholders there instead; you then "prepare" the statement for execution and then, when you execute it, you provide values for those placeholders.

Comment: oh sorry, I didnt have time then, but I just read the blog and I really like these prepared statements, for now I'm going to go with double quotes, but I will look deeper into prepared statements very soon! Thanks!

Comment: would I need to escape the string or use two single quotes if I used prepared statements? Or do they add that security themselves?

Comment: @JahanzebKhan: No, you wouldn't need to perform any escaping; you don't even need to add quotes around strings - it's all handled for you.